# How to make slide the content in HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

[image]

The above image is my front page when I will click on the circle it will open the remaining navigation bar.

[image: 2]

But when I click on the circle icon that I made for navigation it open, but the whole navigations not displayed so what should do to make slide to see all navigations?

This is my HTML file I had made the navigation bar, but my list of navigation is more and its not displaying properly. How can I make the navigation to slide in?

```
<?php
//map based on Bar

$map = [
    'Bar'  => 1, 
    'Pascal' =>100000 ,
    'Pound per square inch' => 14.5038 , 
    'Standard atmosphere' => 0.986923,
    'Torr' => 750.062,

    
    
];

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $fromUnit = $_POST['fromUnit']  ?? '';
    $toUnit = $_POST['toUnit']  ?? '';
    $Pressure = $_POST['Pressure'] ?? '';
    $result = $map[$toUnit] / $map[$fromUnit];
   
}


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<!-- add icon link -->
        <link rel = "icon" href =  
"https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/cdn-uploads/gfg_200X200.png" 
        type = "image/x-icon"> 
        
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Data Rate Convertor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pikaday/1.6.1/css/pikaday.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/untitled.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="navbar.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
    
</head>

<body>
    <nav style="background:linear-gradient(-135deg, #c850c0, #4158d0)"class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-lg fixed-top bg-white portfolio-navbar gradient">
    <div class="container"><a class="navbar-brand logo" href="#">SimplyCalculate</a>
    
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"
            id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="">Standard Calculator</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Scientific Calculator</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Date calculator</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Fuel Economy</a></li>
            

            </ul>
        </div><input type="checkbox" id="active">
    <label for="active" class="menu-btn"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></label>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <ul>
<li><a href="#">Area Convertor</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Data Transfer Rate</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Digital Storage</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Energy Convertor</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Frequency Convertor</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Length Convertor</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Mass Convertor</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Plane Angle Convertor</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Pressure Convertor</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Speed Convertor</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Temperature Convertor</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Time Convertor</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Volume Convertor</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
 
<div id="main">
<!-- Add all your websites page content here  -->
</div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"
                id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <main class="page contact-page">
        <section class="portfolio-block contact">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="heading">
                    <h2>Pressure Convertor</h2>
                </div>
                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group"><label for="Pressure">Enter Pressure value to be converted:</label>
                    <input class="form-control item" id="Pressure" type="number" name="Pressure" value="<?php echo (!empty($Pressure)) ? $Pressure : '' ?>">
                    </div>
                     <div class="form-group"><label for="fromUnit">Convert From</label>
                    <select name="fromUnit" id="fromUnit" class="form-control">
    <option selected>Choose</option>
        <option value="Bar">Bar </option>
        <option value="Pascal">Pascal </option>
        <option value="Pound per square inch">Pound per square inch</option>
        <option value="Standard atmosphere">Standard atmosphere</option>
        <option value="Torr">Torr</option>
        
    </select></div>
     <div class="form-group"><label for="toUnit">Convert To</label>
                    <select name="toUnit" id="toUnit" class="form-control">
        <option  selected >Choose</option>
         <option value="Bar">Bar </option>
        <option value="Pascal">Pascal </option>
        <option value="Pound per square inch">Pound per square inch</option>
        <option value="Standard atmosphere">Standard atmosphere</option>
        <option value="Torr">Torr</option>
</select></div>
                    <div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" name="submit" type="submit" value="Convert">Convert Pressure</button></div>
                    
                </form>
            </div>
            <?php 
            if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
            { 
            echo "<center><b>$Pressure $fromUnit = " . $_POST['Pressure'] * $result . " $toUnit</b></center>";
            } 
            ?>
        </section>
    </main>
    <footer class="page-footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="links"></div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pikaday/1.6.1/pikaday.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/theme.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is CSS for my navigation. What should I change to make the navigation to look perfect?

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
.wrapper{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(-135deg, #c850c0, #4158d0);
  /* background: linear-gradient(375deg, #1cc7d0, #2ede98); */
  /* clip-path: circle(25px at calc(0% + 45px) 45px); */
  clip-path: circle(25px at calc(100% - 45px) 45px);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
#active:checked ~ .wrapper{
  clip-path: circle(100%);
}
.menu-btn{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  right: 20px;
  /* left: 20px; */
  top: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: linear-gradient(-135deg, #c850c0, #4158d0);
  /* background: linear-gradient(375deg, #1cc7d0, #2ede98); */
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
#active:checked ~ .menu-btn{
  background: #fff;
  color: #4158d0;
}
#active:checked ~ .menu-btn i:before{
  content: "\f00d";
}
.wrapper ul{
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.wrapper ul li{
  margin: 15px 0;
}
.wrapper ul li a{
  color: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 200;
  padding: 5px 30px;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 50px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.wrapper ul li a:after{
  position: relative;
  content: "";
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 50px;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}
.wrapper ul li a:hover:after{
  transform: scaleY(1);
}
.wrapper ul li a:hover{
  color: #4158d0;
}
input[type="checkbox"]{
  display:none;
}
.content{
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: -1;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  color: #202020;
}
.content .title{
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.content p{
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

### OR how can I make the drop down list for displaying the all navigations ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drop down list is scrollable as it is so long.

You can change the font-size of its elements down a bit to make it fit on more devices without scrolling, but with a long list it may not be possible to change the size down enough and still have it readable on very small devices.

One thing you can do is choose a font size that is proportional to the size of the device (e.g. using vh units) but be wary of that as you can end up with very small, unreadable characters.

Answer (score 1):

Just make the font size little bit smaller.

One thing you can do adjust the font size according to your screen-size. Use media queries in css.